# Using sed to print range when pattern is inside the range?

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

I have a log file full of queries, and I only want to see the queries that have an error.  The log entries look something like:

```
path to file executing query
QUERY
SIZE: ...
ROWS: ...
MSG: ...
DURATION: ...
```

I want to print all of this stuff, but only when `MSG:` contains something of interest (an error message).  All I've got right now is the `sed -n '/^path to file/,/^DURATION/'` and I have no idea where to go from here.

Note: Queries are often multiline, so using grep's `-B` sadly doesn't work all the time (this is what I've been doing thus far, just being generous with the `-B` value)

Somehow I'd like to use only `sed`, but if I absolutely must use something else like `awk` I guess that's fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't said what an error message looks like, so I'll assume it contains the word "ERROR":

```
sed -n '/^MSG.*ERROR/{H;g;N;p;};/^DURATION/{s/.*//;h;d;};H' < logname
```

(I wish there were a tidier way to purge the hold space. Anyone?...)

Comment: The error message just has something between the `MSG:` and the line ending...

It appears that this solution fits the bill perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be tidier and it doesn't output an extra newline at the beginning: `sed -n '/^QUERY/{h;b};/^MSG.*ERROR/{H;g;N;p;};/^DURATION/d;H'`

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: interesting. I'll do you one better: `sed -n '/^QUERY/{h;b};/^MSG.*ERROR/{H;g;N;p;};H'`

Comment: Oh, even better! `sed -n '/^QUERY/{h;d;};/^MSG.*ERROR/{H;g;N;p;};H'`

Comment: On second thought, I have to eat my words. These improved solutions (last three comments) fail to print the path. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Thanks for the help again! Sorry I didn't notice your newer comments until now :)  Your original solution is currently working perfectly!

Comment: In GNU sed, you can use `z` in place of `s/.*//`: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-Commands.html#index-Emptying-pattern-space
However, it says explicitly, “there is no portable way to clear sed’s buffers in the middle of the script in most multibyte locales.”

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved with a little more explanation. What's the gist, find line with pattern and then do some sed branching, find the end pattern, do delete all substitution, then some more sed labeling jumping around? It's hard to adapt this solution if one is not a sed wizards

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest a solution with `grep`. That will work if the structure in the log file is always the same as above (i.e. MSG is in the 5th line, and one line follows):

```
egrep -i '^MSG:.*error' -A 1 -B 4 logfile
```

That means: If the word `error` occurs in a `MSG` line then output the block beginning from 4 lines before `MSG` till one line after it.
Of course you have to adjust the regexp to recognize an error.

This will not work if the structure of those blocks differs.

Comment: I wish I could rely on the queries being only a single line... I've been using `grep` and `-B10` to get the vast majority of the queries that fail.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the [cgrep.sed](http://examples.oreilly.com/upt2/split/cgrep.sed) script, as described by [Unix Power Tools](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003302) book