# Shell script using sed to remove HTML tag containing specific text

Tags: bash, shell, sed, pattern-matching

I am looking for a way to delete (with sed if possible) an html tag containing a specific word.
For instance, delete every **div** tag containing the word **foo**. The divs can of course contain multiple lines. For instance :

```
<body>
    <div>
        This div will be <i>deleted</i>.
        Why ?
        Because it contains foo.
    </div>

    <div>
        This div doesn't contains the forbidden word.
        <b>So it won't be deleted.</b>
    </div>
</body>
```

I found ways to delete html tags, but nothing about tags containing a specific text. Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am not a sed expert. At all. But I have spent some time looking around for a solution and didn't find anything that could help me so far.

Comment: Use a language that has a proper HTML parser available. `sed` will only handle, for example, nested `div`s with great difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with sed alone. Sed is a single-line processor. If you want a script using sed/bash/grep, you would need to create a parser that will parse div contents and only print the divs that don't contain the text you wanted. Seriously, look for a html parser instead.

Comment: This is not impossible with sed, just a bit cumbersome and there are better ways to do it, see, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341158/using-sed-to-print-range-when-pattern-is-inside-the-range. But impossible it is not!